# v8 performance guidelines

Tags: javascript, v8

I tend to use the factory method to construct my objects in javascript without the `this` keyword. For example:

```
var PointA = function(x, y) {
  var z = {};
  z.x = x;
  z.y = y;
  return z;
};
var z0 = PointA(1, 2);
```

I've seen several examples illustrating how v8 uses hidden classes to attain fast property lookup, but all these examples employ the standard technique of object construction, namely:

```
var PointB = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};
var z0 = new PointB(1, 2);
```

If I use a nontraditional factory like `PointA` am I thwarting the hidden class optimizers of v8?

Comment: You can still write it using a regular constructor and `this`, but call it without `new`.

Comment: These 2 snippets produce different objects. How is it possible to compare incomparable? Make it right first then make it fast.

Comment: @zerkms: Let's assume the prototype is not used anyway. And you should still be able to tell whether `PointA` does produce a hidden class or not.

Comment: @Bergi: it must be since the properties are dynamically added to the object referred by `z`

Comment: z=Object.create(null) would be faster in V8 than z={} since it doesn't setup inheritance.

Comment: @zerkms: In what way specifically are these objects different? They both have an `x` property and a `y` property. Are you referring to the prototype? Does the prototype affect v8 hidden classes?

Comment: @gloo: `z0 instanceof PointA`, `z1 instanceof PointB` --- that's how they are different. About other questions - I'm not confident enough to state anything for sure.

Comment: @dandavis `Object.create(x)` in V8 is implemented via `{__proto__: x}` which is actually somewhat slower than just `{}`.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov: Object.create(null) is special. run some benchmarks if you don't believe me...

Comment: @dandavis this is not the question of belief, this is a question of knowing how things are implemented (and I happen to know how they are implemented in an intricate detail). the simplest microbenchmark shows that `Object.create` is slower than `{}` by a big margin: http://jsperf.com/ubench-literal-vs-oc. As I said before: `Object.create(x)` is implemented through `{__proto__:x}` so it can't be faster than `{}`. Now, it is considerably slower because `__proto__` change always requires a roundtrip into runtime, on the other hand in optimized code `{}` is just a handful of inlined instructions.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov: there is more to an app than instantiating empty objects. Many real-world operations, especially iterations, execute faster on objects created via create(null). Switching from a literal recently gave me quite a boost in a nodejs app, even though it takes longer to construct...

Comment: @dandavis well, that is certainly true, microbenchmarks are meaningless, I say that myself all the time. however that's not what we were talking about here: we were talking about pure construction time in vacuum and based on just that we can't recommend to use `Object.create(null)` over `{}`. There are of course various scenarios where `Object.create(null)` can be beneficial (e.g. not having a hidden class transition tree interference like illustrated in my answer below) but that's a separate matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JavaScript objects in V8 are using hidden classes machinery, so it does not matter whether you create an object via a constructor or from a literal --- both will have hidden classes.

What matters here however is how hidden classes are connected to each other. Hidden classes are forming transition trees with a root attached to the constructor. If you are creating objects from a literal it means your transition tree is essentially growing from the `Object` constructor. This can confuse V8 sometimes because transition trees that are logically disconnected seem to be connected to V8 at their root. Take a look at [this](http://jsperf.com/transition-conflict) jsPerf microbenchmark. I create two objects that are seemingly disconnected:

```js
function X() {
  var self = {};
  self.x = 0.1;
  return self;
}

function Y() {
  var self = {};
  self.x = true;
  return self;
}

var y = new Y, x = new X;
```

Yet internally V8 can't select the most efficient representation for the property `x` on objects made by `X` because it also sees objects made by `Y` as part of the same hidden class transition tree. If you make an object through a constructor that starts a new transition tree and a result there is no type polution.